# How to generate documentation for Vue 3 project (Vite). (components, pages, props, methods etc.)

Tags: vue.js, documentation, vite

Faced with problem to generate simple documentation for vue project. Any thoughts?

Tried the Vue Styleguidist but it's doesn't work with Vue 3 and Vite.

Answer (score -1):

I use `vue-docgen-cli` with an heavy `docgen.config.js` to make it accepts an initial comment in the SFC file containing `@component` description. Then you have to JSDoc comment properties and emits.

Comment: JSdoc wants vue-template-compiler but with vite we dont have it. @Andriy Liashok did u find any solution ?

Comment: Sorry @simpledev, I don't understand your comment. As I said, `vue-docgen-cli` with a custom `docgen.config.js` generates the needed documentation. And my project uses `vite`.